# Swagger 2 mark all fields as parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

In Spring Boot 2 I us an object to hold a set of parameters as below. Question is how to document EACH field in swagger as a parameter. Currently swagger-ui presents a single parameter as an object instead of each field in the object being a parameter.

```
  @GetMapping(path = "/date", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @Operation(summary = "Blah blah.")
  public ResponseDto getTacreps(
      @Valid QueryParametersDto queryParametersDto) {...}


@Value
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
public class QueryParametersDto {

  @JsonProperty(USER_SELECTED_AUTHORITIES)
  @NotBlank
  private final String userSelectedAuthorities;

  @JsonProperty(JUSTIFICATION)
  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 1, max = 4000)
  private final String justification;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, mark the controller method argument as `@ParameterObject`:

```
public ResponseDto getTacreps( @Valid @ParameterObject QueryParametersDto queryParametersDto) {...}
```

As described in [Springdoc](https://springdoc.org/index.html#how-can-i-extract-fields-from-parameter-object):

> Request parameter annotated with `@ParameterObject` will help adding
> each field of the parameter as a separate request parameter.